# Making alias for context paths?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to be able to do `s'Graph` and `c'Graph` to refer to `System'Graph` and `Combinatorica'Graph` (and other functions conflicting with Combinatorica) is there a way to do this?

Following Simon's idea, the following seems to work

```
{Set @@ {ToExpression["c" <> Last[StringSplit[#, "`"]]], 
      ToExpression[#]}} & /@ Names["Combinatorica`*"];
{Set @@ {ToExpression["s" <> Last[StringSplit[#, "`"]]], 
      ToExpression[#]}} & /@ Names["System`*"];
```

Now `cCompleteGraph[5]` and `sCompleteGraph[5]` return `Combinatorica` and `System` graphs respectively

**Update Jan 8th**
For future reference, this is the method I ended up using to use `GraphUtilities`, `Combinatorica` and built-in graph functionality together. It resolves conflict by remapping all combinatorica functions like `Graph` to `cGraph` and changes `$Post` to remove GraphUtilities and Combinatorica from ContextPath on each evaluation, necessary because `GraphUtilities'ToCombinatoricaGraph` adds `Combinatorica` to `$ContextPath` at every call.

To summarize, execute the code below at start of each session. Combinatorica func is now `cfunc`, GraphUtilities func is `GraphUtilities'func`, and built-in func is just `func`

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
combNames = Names["Combinatorica`*"];
{Set @@ {ToExpression["c" <> Last[StringSplit[#, "`"]]], 
      ToExpression[#]}} & /@ Names["Combinatorica`*"];
Needs["GraphUtilities`"];
$ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "Combinatorica`"];
$Post = ($ContextPath = 
     DeleteCases[$ContextPath, 
      "Combinatorica`" | "GraphUtilities`"]; #) &;
```

Comment: How many different symbols do you need? Would it be feasible to just do cGraph=Combinatorica`Graph (and keep Combinatorica of $ContextPath)?

Comment: Is this a v8 thing, by the way? On my v7 system `Intersection @@ (Names[# <> "\`*"] & /@ {"Combinatorica", "System"})` returns an empty list.

Comment: Yup, version 8, there are now two types of Graph objects, seems like WRI is on the way to replace Combinatorica's functionality with built-ins

Comment: Could you define the new contexts 'c' and 's' and use `Names[]` to programatically  create aliases for all of the symbols in each of `Combinatorica` and `System`?

Comment: Neat idea! I don't even need a context this way, just prepend a single symbol to the method

Comment: Minor issue is that now some of my defined variables highlight as if they don't exist...maybe 4500 custom symbol definitions is too much...I wonder if there's a way to get only "new in 8.0" symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
$PreRead = # /. {str_String :> 
     StringReplace[
      str, {RegularExpression["^s`(.*)"] :> "System`" <> "$1", 
       RegularExpression["^c`(.*)"] :> "Combinatorica`" <> "$1"}]} &
```

Of course, this is working at a very low level, so take care.

Comment: This gives `StringReplace::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringReplace[RowBox[{2,+,5}],{RegularExpression[^s`(.*)]:>System`<>$1,RegularExpression[^c`(.*)]:>Combinatorica`<>$1}].`

Comment: It seems "c`CompleteGraph[5]" turns into "RowBox[List["c`CompleteGraph","[","5","]"]]" before getting passed to $PreRead

Comment: @Yaroslav: fixed now.  That's what I get for only testing on symbols and not more general expressions.  (Hence the comment to take care when using $PreRead. :-)